# Can I upgrade my flat handlebars to drop handlebars

Tags: hybrid-bike, conversion, giant, drop-bar

I have a Giant Escape 3 Disc https://www.martinsbike.com/product/giant-escape-3-disc-383035-1.htm
I usually ride about 10 miles every day, and I really like the look and feel of drop handlebars. is it possible to convert from flat to drop, and if it is, would it be worth it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting hybrid to gravel bike, flat to drop bars and brifters?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72520/converting-hybrid-to-gravel-bike-flat-to-drop-bars-and-brifters), although you have mechanical disc brakes.  Have a look on this site for other questions around flat to drop bar conversions.

Comment: Yes it's possible, yes it has been asked before, and yes it is costly.  Have a read of the existing questions/answers on the same topic.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76200/  and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/74546/ and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/ so this will get closed as a duplicate.  Don't take it badly - Stackexchange prefers to improve existing answers rather than have the same question asked periodically.